# Connecting to AWS From and Oracle Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, oracle19c

I have an issue relating to a local Oracle server (19c) creating a link to AWS via IAM user.

I have an access key for the AWS IAM user, and AWS automatically generates a secret key (password) associated with the access key. Now the secret key is about 40chars long.
In Oracle 19c the maximum length for an identifier is 30chars!?
Meaning when I try using JDBC to connect Oracle to AWS I get an error (ORA-00972: identifier is too long).

Has anyone experienced something like this? Any workarounds?
Help would be much appreciated

I have tried to customize the secret key length associated with the access key in AWS IAM, but it seems to be auto-generated.

Comment: The word 'identifier' typically relates to a key, not its associated value (e.g. wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY).